# Ubuntu 18.04 Freezes After I Start

Tags: freeze

I've checked some of the other answers here, but they didn't seem to solve my issue.

My specific problem is that I start my Ubuntu virtual machine using Virtual Box, and it freezes after it boots. I disabled the password log in so it just stays on the desktop screen, without letting me click or do anything.

I've tried increasing the number of processors from 1 to 4, and enabled PAE/NX but that didn't work.

Just for some extra background info, before I shut down my machine most recently, I spent a good amount of time installing the SciPy libraries and also CUDA and cuDNN. I was actually having some problems getting the GPU to work and so shut down the machine to do it later, only to find that the machine completely freezes now.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what to do and on what's wrong?\

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use CUDA and GPU on a VB machine. Installing it was wrong.

Comment: Oh my goodness I had no idea... Okay, thank you. I guess I'll have to stick with Windows for now.